# Is capillary pressure significant?

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics, estimation, capillary-action

I have a hydraulic system pressure to be measured in cm of water. It is done by tapping a graded tube, and simply measuring the height of the water column (usually at around 10-20 cm of water).
If I tap down into that system using a 9 cm long 22-Gauge needle, is the capillary pressure significant enough to be added to that pressure, or can I just add that height as a normal water column?

Comment: More of an Engineering Stack Exchange question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find capilary pressure by poking a still water with that tube, and measuring how high will the water level in the tube rise, when in contact with zero added pressure water, like a large droplet on the table.

Once you have this, consider it to be a zero. And measure water height only above this mark as additional pressure.

Once capilar is filled, it doesnt itself provide additional pressure to the vessel. Except in cases where the process of filling the capilary itself is critical, like from a closed vessel, as this will drop the pressure in the vessel, as some fluid is removed from the vessel.

By measuring water level in the capilary from a still water, you can find the capilarry pressure, by measuring the water height. But I guess you dont actually need it. Just assume that once capilary is filled, it doesnt provide any more pressure.